# passing an undeclared reference through PHP

Tags: php

So currently, I'm making a music database online. The part I'm trying to implement is a playlist function so that given a list of your playlists, you can click one and view the music. What I have is this:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $playlist))
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        echo "<h1 style='text-align:center;'>Playlists</h1>";
        echo "<table style='width:100%'>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . '<a href="getPlaylist.php>' . $row['name']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_free_result($result);
```

So I need it so that once someone clicks the link, it will transition them into getPlayList.php and also send over the name in the link, (technically $row['name']) so that I can actually pull up the information in the SQL database. I've tried doing things like:

```
echo "<td>" . '<a href="getPlaylist.php?link=' . $row["name"]. '">' . $row['name']."</td>";
```

but to no avail. Can anyone help?

edit:
So what this segment is supposed to do is, it makes a table with each row having a link to a different playlist, but they all go to "getPlaylist.php" where using the name of the link clicked, it will then retrieve all the songs that exist inside it.

Comment: Do you get redirected to getPlaylist.php? Where do you go after clicking? Maybe you are missing a "/" before it?

Comment: yes, moving to the link is fine, I just need to be able to be able to pass this variable along with it.

Comment: What is the url after moving to the link..?done

Comment: What does your redirect looks like? getPlaylist.php?link=  BLANK?

And you haven't closed your `<a>` tag.

Comment: @pokeybit that should not be an issue now should it..?done

Comment: I get redirected but I only have a blank page at the moment because I haven't fully set the page up, because I need to be able to send over the variable name that's being clicked on
edit: I closed the </a> tag and it still works the same

Comment: It should not stop the `$row['name']` appearing correct. But it will stop your page from being formatted correctly as the A link will spread till the next </a>. Does `$row['name']` show some text?

Comment: `echo "<td>" . '<a href="getPlaylist.php?link=' . $row["name"]. '">' . $row['name']."</a></td>";` If `$row['name']` is in deed set and contains a string it would work fine.

Comment: The variable will be available in `$_GET['link']` on the `getPlaylist.php` page

Comment: ah, thanks RamRaider, I think that works

Answer (score 0):

edit: solved thanks to RamRaider
I had to use $_GET['link'] in getPlaylist.php

Comment: :) good news @SirBearLag ~ good luck with the rest of your project